# Не регистрируются пользователи в веб приложении на flask

Tags: python, база-данных, веб-программирование, flask, sqlalchemy

Пишу приложение на фласке с нуля, и нужно было сделать страницу с регистрацией пользователей, но почему-то после нажатия на кнопку регистрации поля обновляются и ничего не происходит(пользователь не добавляется в базу данных, редирект не срабатывает).

Код модели пользователя для регистрации:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False, unique=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(32), nullable=False)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    phone_number = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, unique=True)
```

Форма пользователя для представления в шаблоне:

```
class RegisterForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired('This field is necessary!')])
    password = PasswordField('Password')

    first_name = StringField('First Name', validators=[DataRequired('This field is necessary!')])
    last_name = StringField('Last Name', validators=[DataRequired('This field is necessary!')])
    phone_number = StringField('Phone Number', validators=[DataRequired('This field is necessary!')])

    submit = SubmitField('Sign Up')
```

Сама функция регистрации:

```
@app.route('/user/register/')
def register():
    form = RegisterForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        username = form.username.data

        password = form.password.data
        password = hashlib.md5(password.encode()).hexdigest()

        first_name = form.first_name.data
        last_name = form.last_name.data
        phone_number = form.phone_number.data

        user = User(username=username, password=password, first_name=first_name, \
            last_name=last_name, phone_number=phone_number)

        db.session.add(user)
        db.commit()

        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('register.html', form=form)
```

И шаблон:

```
 {% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <form>
        <h2>Sign Up</h2>
        <form action="" method="post" novalidate>
            {{ form.csrf_token }}

            <p>
                {{ form.username.label }}
                {{ form.username(size=50) }}
            </p>

            <p>
                {{ form.password.label }}
                {{ form.password() }}
            </p>

            <p>
                {{ form.first_name.label }}
                {{ form.first_name(size=50) }}
            </p>

            <p>
                {{ form.last_name.label }}
                {{ form.last_name(size=50) }}
            </p>

            <p>
                {{ form.phone_number.label }}
                {{ form.phone_number(size=20) }}
            </p>

            {{ form.submit }}
        </form>
    </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Я уже раньше писал приложения на фласке, это было давно, но тогда никаких проблем с базой данных и с добавлением в неё новых объектов не было. Подскажите пожалуйста, что здесь не так и как это фиксить?

Comment: Кажется я понял в чём проблема. При отправке запроса он почему-то отправляется как GET, хотя я явно указал метод POST в форме. Почему это может быть?

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что всё дело в представлении, а если быть более точным, то в декоратор не был передан список `methods`:

```
@app.route('/user/register/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = RegisterForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        username = form.username.data

        password = form.password.data
        password = hashlib.md5(password.encode()).hexdigest()

        first_name = form.first_name.data
        last_name = form.last_name.data
        phone_number = form.phone_number.data

        user = User(username=username, password=password, first_name=first_name, \
            last_name=last_name, phone_number=phone_number)

        db.session.add(user)
        db.commit()

        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('register.html', form=form)
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо товарищу @narnik-gamarnik За ответ. Это мне частично помогло исправить проблему. Кроме того, я заметил, что сделал глупую ошибку, я случайно забыл удалить предыдущую форму, которую я оставлял ещё до того как использовал модуль FlaskForms. Шаблон html должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <h2>Sign Up</h2>
    <form action="{{ url_for('register') }}" method="POST">
        {{ form.csrf_token }}

        <p>
            {{ form.username.label }}
            {{ form.username(size=50) }}
        </p>

        <p>
            {{ form.password.label }}
            {{ form.password() }}
        </p>

        <p>
            {{ form.first_name.label }}
            {{ form.first_name(size=50) }}
        </p>

        <p>
            {{ form.last_name.label }}
            {{ form.last_name(size=50) }}
        </p>

        <p>
            {{ form.phone_number.label }}
            {{ form.phone_number(size=20) }}
        </p>

        {{ form.submit }}
    </form>
{% endblock content %}
```